# cross-env/dist/index.js:42 unexpected token }

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

A little background: I'm developing a Laravel 5 application. I'm developing locally on Windows 7 using Homestead (using Vagrant/VirtualBox) and deploying to an Amazon EC2 instance through CodePipeline.

While trying to get Laravel Mix working locally, I kept running into a cacophony of errors that eventually led me to the solution of installing cross-env globally rather than including it in the devDependencies in `package.json`. Of course, this also means that my Amazon deployment needed to be updated to that setup as well. None of this is really relevant except to explain that cross-env is installed globally on my deployment, in case that's relevant.

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.1.10"
    }
}
```

My deployment to AWS fails on `npm run production` with the following error:

```
[stderr]/usr/lib/node_modules/cross-env/dist/index.js:42
[stderr]    });
[stderr]    ^
[stderr]SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

What could be causing this issue? And how can I resolve it? I highly doubt that there's *actually* a syntax error in cross-env.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and i could fix it by updating node and re-installing npm.

Steps that worked for me:

Update Node using a package manager:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then fresh install:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. (I have a feeling this is a bit like hitting a nail with a sledge hammer, but it is a fast enough fix, so it is perfect.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to upgrade both nodejs and npm:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.2/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xJf node-v6.9.2-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Then I run `npm install` without any errors.