# Laravel: I cant compile SASS

Tags: laravel

I am trying to compile SASS using npm run on Laravel 6. The command generates the error below.
I also followed the steps below:

- Step 1: composer update
- Step 2: rm -rf node_modules
- Step 3: npm cache clean
- Step 4: npm install
- Step 5: npm outdated
- Step 6: npm install
- Step 7: npm run dev

  **Error**

  ```
    C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-vue\advanced\node_modules\cross-env\src\index.js:23
      )
      ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
      at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
      at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-vue\advanced\node_modules\cross-env\src\bin\cross-env.js:3:18)
  ```

  **My package.json file**

  ```
  {
   "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "npm run development",
  "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
  "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
  "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "prod": "npm run production",
  "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
  "cross-env": "^7.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2",
  "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
  "lodash": "^4.17.13",
  "popper.js": "^1.12",
  "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
  "sass": "^1.20.1",
  "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "vue": "^2.5.17",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Try upgrading/reinstalling node: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171302/9556193